# How to catch all uncaught errors in a dart polymer app?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-async

I want to put in a handler that will catch all unhandled errors in a Polymer app.

I figured `Zone` would be the trick so tried

```dart
void main() {
  runZoned(() => initPolymer(), onError: (e, stackTrace) {
    _log.shout('TOP ZONE', e, stackTrace);
  });
}
```

But that doesn't work. The errors never get to this error handler.

Not sure if this relates to http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15854

How do people handle this?

Comment: Actually I think this might be related to the issue I referenced. If I throw when making a rest call it works

Answer (score 4):

How about using [Window.onError](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.Window#id_onError).

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  window.onError.listen((ErrorEvent e) => print(e.message));
  throw 'boom!';
}
```

Comment: As far as I remember this only catches JS errors but I'm not sure. Worth a try.

Comment: Tried it. This does catch Dart exceptions. Works with dart2js and Dartium.

Comment: In the end I used a combination of this and the isolate onError as you get proper dart exceptions from the isolate

Comment: Do you mean Isolate.addErrorListener()? Or Isolate.errors.listen()? Does that work in dart2js yet? It's new in 1.9 I think.

Answer (score 0):

So I know we have gotten error handling to work using the following construct:

```
runZoned(() {
   return initPolymer().run(() => Polymer.onReady
       .then(doSomeStuff)
       .whenComplete(doSomeCompleting));
 },
 onError: (err, [stackTrace]) {
   logger.severe("Received an error", err, stackTrace);
 });
```

I have posted it in the interest of helping you quickly. I dont have a great explanation off the top of my head why your version isn't working at the moment. Ill do some digging and see if I can work out what is really different.

Comment: Thanks Adam. This looks like essentially what I have. This catches most things but it doesn't seem to catch all things that blow up in the js code inside the core and paper elements