# Dart - angular2 - try catch in component to catch a javascript error

Tags: angular, dart

I have the following code :

```
try {
  js.context.callMethod(r'myJavascriptMethod', [
  ]);
} catch (e) {
  handleError();
}
```

I'd like to catch any error from `myJavascriptMethod`, but when an exception is thrown, nothing is caught.

Comment: What's the exception and the stack trace?

Comment: In my javascript code, I test with `throw "Error";`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549222/how-to-catch-all-uncaught-errors-in-a-dart-polymer-app might provide some ideas

Comment: Thanks - `window.onError.listen((ErrorEvent e)` did the job.