# catch any error in angular dart (like angular's ErrorHandler)

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I need to catch any front end (angulardart) error and send it back to the server.

I saw there is something like his in regular Angular [ErrorHandler](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/global-error-handling-with-angular2-6b992bdfb59c), but I can't find any equivalent in angular dart (or dart it self).

Maybe I should hack the Exception object's constructor, but I don't find it a good approach (assuming it's possible)

any hints please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dart it's quite similar:

```
@Injectable()
class ErrorHandler implements ExceptionHandler {
  ApplicationRef _appRef;

  ErrorHandler(Injector injector) {
    // prevent DI circular dependency
    new Future<Null>.delayed(Duration.ZERO, () {
      _appRef = injector.get(ApplicationRef) as ApplicationRef;
    });
  }

  @override
  void call(dynamic exception, [dynamic stackTrace, String reason]) {
    final stackTraceParam = stackTrace is StackTrace
        ? stackTrace
        : (stackTrace is String
            ? new StackTrace.fromString(stackTrace)
            : (stackTrace is List
                ? new StackTrace.fromString(stackTrace.join('\n'))
                : null));
    _log.shout(reason ?? exception, exception, stackTraceParam);

    // We can try to get an error shown, but don't assume the app is
    // in a healthy state after this error handler was reached.
    // You can for example still instruct the user to reload the 
    // page with danger to cause hare because of inconsistent
    // application state..
    // To get changes shown, we need to explicitly invoke change detection. 
    _appRef?.tick();
  }
}
```

Provide the error handler

```
return bootstrap(AppComponent, [const Provide(ExceptionHandler, useClass: ErrorHandler)]);
```

For errors that might be caused outside Angular, see also [How to catch all uncaught errors in a dart polymer app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549222/how-to-catch-all-uncaught-errors-in-a-dart-polymer-app)

Comment: Thanks, this is typically for uncatched exceptions. Is there a solution to get notified about catched ones?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with catched ones. These catched by your custom code or catched anywhere in Angular or any component used in the app?

Comment: I mean catched by my custom code. Those catches should maybe be centrally handled by my own catch logic?

Comment: I'm thinking as if my app view was treated in the back-end (old school), I'd have all errors that happen in the view in my logs along with service methods exceptions. If anything goes wrong on the js front-end, we cannot know about it unless we catch it and send it back to the server

Comment: If they are uncaught, above `ErrorHandler` is invoked. If you catch them and want report them use `try { ... } catch(e, s) { logService.logException(e, s); rethrow; }`. I think if you can handle them, they are not really errors and there should be no need to report them. If you can't handle them, you shouldn't catch them and then they will be handled by the `ErrorHandler` anyway.

Comment: Theoretically it's simple, but if you don't know you catched an error that you can't handle, you will never know about it and never report it to the back office. So users will complain and you will not know what is happening in their front ends (or know it when there are hundreds of them who are insulting the company)

Comment: I think we're moving to a philosophical discussion :-): catching only exceptions we know will happen is te ideal case, but since we have the issue of JS that handles very badly exceptions, we cannot ask the user to refresh the page on every exception: 
// We can try to get an error shown, but don't assume the app is
    // in a healthy state after this error handler was reached.

Comment: Maybe zones are a solution, it is anyway sad that we have to handle all these specifics to have a java equivalent stability : https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/zones

Comment: Angular is already running in a zone. I am still not sure what you try to accomplish. I also don't understand what you mean with "JS that handles very badly exceptions" or how this is related.

Comment: Günter, I have used your function as example and now I'm able to catch the errors, but I cannot figure out how I can show a window/popup to inform the user. Can you please give an hint?

Comment: You should be able to inject the router and call `router.navigate...`. You might need to run `_appRef?.tick();` afterwards to invoke change detection.